# What version of jQuery does Drupal 8 use?

Tags: 8, javascript

How can I find out what version of jQuery a particular release of Drupal 8 core is using?

Comment: I've made a small change to the question so it's less of a moving target for the future, I'm pretty sure your original intent is covered by the new version. Any problems just edit or let me know

Comment: @Clive: Why not remove the "8" from the title, question and tags also? Same question applies for any release of Drupal, no?

Comment: @Pierre ... no it doesn't. I'm asking what version of jQuery is for Drupal 8. I don't want to know what is Drupal 7 or anything else. It's a very simple basic question that someone can answer in less than 10 seconds vs me looking it up which can take 10-30 minutes. I didn't a quick search and I was not able to find it on google, which is why I asked here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to save some time, you can go to the Javascript console and type `jQuery.fn.jquery` which works on any site using jQuery, not only Drupal sites.

At the moment Drupal 8 core uses jQuery 2.1.4, but it looks like jQuery 3 has been implemented in Drupal 8.4.x.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2533498

Answer (score 9):

This is probably not the best question because the answer could change over time based on the specific version of Drupal.

The most accurate way to find what version of a JavaScript library is used by Drupal core is to look directly at the `core/core.libraries.yml` file for a given version of Drupal. One of the easiest ways to do this is to browse Drupal's git repository online:

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/HEAD/core/core.libraries.yml#n334

```
jquery:
  remote: https://github.com/jquery/jquery
  version: VERSION_HERE
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/VERSION_HERE/MIT-LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js: { minified: true, weight: -20 }
```

For Drupal 6-7, without jquery_update module installed, the version of Drupal can be most easily discovered by going into the `misc/` directory, and looking at the top of the jquery.js file. This is v1.2.6 and v1.4.4 respectively.

For Drupal 5, the version of jquery is not readily apparent, but the handy `git blame misc/jquery.js` reveals the commit [0d57bae](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/commit/misc/jquery.js?h=5.x&id=0d57bae) updated jQuery to v1.0.4.

Comment: Yes, this will change over time, https://www.drupal.org/node/2700741

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8.9.x the version being used is 3.5.1 as you will see here https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.x/core/core.libraries.yml#L365